# MySQL concat & regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm asking a question about the `concatenation function` and `regex`.
I have a fied (`reference`) which looks like :

```
FW123
TS76
FWE8E
K987
HT78
FW345
```

I would like to concatenate all rows which begins by `FW` with `EU` at the end.
So the result must looks like :

```
FW123EU
TS76
FWE8EEU
K987
HT78
FW345EU
```

This is my command line :

```
UPDATE ps2_product 
SET `reference` = CONCAT(^FW[A-Z0-9],EU)
```

It's the first time I handle regex expressions.
The syntax is correct ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `LIKE` :

```
UPDATE ps2_product t
SET t.`reference` = CONCAT(t.`reference`,'EU')
WHERE t.reference LIKE 'FW%'
```

Comment: With `FW%`, even such entries as `FW-###` will get modified, while it seems OP needs to make sure there are uppercase ASCII letters or digits after `FW`.

Comment: @sagi Perfect ! Now I understood how I can use that ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a where condition.

```
UPDATE ps2_product 
SET `reference` = CONCAT(reference,'EU')
WHERE reference REGEXP '^FW[A-Z0-9]+$'
```

Comment: I think the pattern should really be [`^FW[A-Z0-9]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/FUiuUc/1) to only match those entries that start with `FW` and then have 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters or digits up to the end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Two different explanations and I understand very well !

Comment: Yes this one is more complete and to the point as OP pointed out. Thanks for your effort @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by :

**1) Using LIKE and CONCAT :**

```
UPDATE ps2_product  
SET reference = CONCAT(reference,'EU') 
WHERE reference LIKE 'FW%';
```

**2) Using CONCAT, REGEX with WHERE :**

```
UPDATE ps2_product 
SET references = CONCAT(references,'EU') 
WHERE references REGEXP '^FW[A-Z0-9]';
```

**3) Using REGEX, CONCAT and case :**

```
UPDATE ps2_product
SET references = 
CASE
  WHEN references REGEXP '^FW[A-Z0-9]' = 1 THEN CONCAT(references,'EU')
  WHEN references REGEXP '^FW[A-Z0-9]' = 0 THEN references
END;
```